# Identifying URI of my red5 server

Tags: flash, uri, red5

I've installed red5 on my Win7 PC. I want to use shared objects with Flash and Red5. The documentation says that I need URI, and it looks like a URL, but my home server doesn’t have a URL. Is there a way to find out its URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [wikipedia page on URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Relationship_to_URL_and_URN). Then just use your server's IP address and port number.